# "This is us" meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Level Two, Department of Magical Law Enforcement, including the Improper Use of Magic Office, Auror Headquarters and Wizengamot Administration Services."
>
> "**This is us**, Harry," said Mr Weasley, and they followed the witch out of the lift into a corridor lined with doors. "My office is on the other side of the floor."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phenix</sub>

According to the context, "this is us" seems to mean that they had arrived at their floor. But I feel "this is ours" should be used for this. What does "this is us" truly mean here?

Comment: If I work in Microsoft and I see that you're using the Windows operating system on your computer, I could say *this is us*, meaning *it was us who developed this product*, *this is our product* or *this product belongs to us*.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Not recommended, and I respectfully disagree Michael.  You could say “that’s our work” or “we made that”, but it’s a stretch to say “we are that” or “that is us.”  Therefore “that’s us” or “this is us” sounds awkward.

Comment: If you're in an airport and a message goes out over the intercom announcing  that your flight is boarding, you can say "*That's us*, we have to hurry".  In other words,  *That announcement pertains to us/ that is our flight.*  It is not a case of ellipsis of "flight" or in your case not ellipsis of the noun "floor".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo But interestingly also you interpreted it as "that is our *flight*".

Comment: I am paraphrasing there in that hypothetical context, @dan, not suggesting there is an ellipsis of the noun *flight*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an idiom, typical of the speech of slightly older British people (such as Mr Weasely). You might use it on a train, bus or even in a lift to tell someone that "we are at the station/stop/floor that we want"

Compare with "Here we are" instead of "Here ours is." You could use "Here we are" as an alternative to "This is us".

Comment: Agree. It is similar to saying “This is where we should be; by arriving here, we have changed from people who are in the wrong place, to people who are in the right place!”   All in three words!  This is highly idiomatic.